# How to capture the desktop in OpenCV (ie. turn a bitmap into a Mat)?

Tags: opencv, bitmap, desktop, mat

I want to use OpenCV to process my desktop as if it were a video stream.
I am familiar with OpenCV.
I am not familiar with the Windows API.
I realize there are other ways to capture the screen, but for the purposes of my question, I need it to be done using OpenCV.

Here is my (super naive) code:

```
HWND hDesktopWnd;
HDC hDesktopDC;
hDesktopWnd=GetDesktopWindow();
hDesktopDC=GetDC(hDesktopWnd);

// get the height and width of the screen
int height = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYVIRTUALSCREEN);
int width = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXVIRTUALSCREEN);

// create a bitmap
HBITMAP hbDesktop = CreateCompatibleBitmap( hDesktopDC, width, height);

Mat src(height,width,CV_8UC4);
src.data = (uchar*)hbDesktop;

imshow("output",src);  //fails :(
```

There are similar questions on StackOverflow, but they are either for the old-style OpenCV, or for Android operating system.
I'm on windows 7 64x
Opencv 2.4.3

Thanks anyone who can answer this question.

Comment: Did you have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6999830/convert-hbitmap-to-cvmat ?

Comment: yeah, he can't figure it out either

Comment: Super~! Just as a thing, I think you might also need to DeleteObject and DeleteDC/ReleaseDC to avoid memory leaks.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

After **MUCH** trial and error, I managed to write a function to do it.  here it is for anyone else who might want it:

```cpp
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

Mat hwnd2mat(HWND hwnd){

    HDC hwindowDC,hwindowCompatibleDC;

    int height,width,srcheight,srcwidth;
    HBITMAP hbwindow;
    Mat src;
    BITMAPINFOHEADER  bi;
    
    hwindowDC=GetDC(hwnd);
    hwindowCompatibleDC=CreateCompatibleDC(hwindowDC);
    SetStretchBltMode(hwindowCompatibleDC,COLORONCOLOR);  
    
    RECT windowsize;    // get the height and width of the screen
    GetClientRect(hwnd, &windowsize);

    srcheight = windowsize.bottom;
    srcwidth = windowsize.right;
    height = windowsize.bottom/2;  //change this to whatever size you want to resize to
    width = windowsize.right/2;
    
    src.create(height,width,CV_8UC4);

    // create a bitmap
    hbwindow = CreateCompatibleBitmap( hwindowDC, width, height);
    bi.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);    //http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/window/dd183402%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
    bi.biWidth = width;    
    bi.biHeight = -height;  //this is the line that makes it draw upside down or not
    bi.biPlanes = 1;    
    bi.biBitCount = 32;    
    bi.biCompression = BI_RGB;    
    bi.biSizeImage = 0;  
    bi.biXPelsPerMeter = 0;    
    bi.biYPelsPerMeter = 0;    
    bi.biClrUsed = 0;    
    bi.biClrImportant = 0;
    
    // use the previously created device context with the bitmap
    SelectObject(hwindowCompatibleDC, hbwindow);
    // copy from the window device context to the bitmap device context
    StretchBlt( hwindowCompatibleDC, 0,0, width, height, hwindowDC, 0, 0,srcwidth,srcheight, SRCCOPY); //change SRCCOPY to NOTSRCCOPY for wacky colors !
    GetDIBits(hwindowCompatibleDC,hbwindow,0,height,src.data,(BITMAPINFO *)&bi,DIB_RGB_COLORS);  //copy from hwindowCompatibleDC to hbwindow

    // avoid memory leak
    DeleteObject (hbwindow); DeleteDC(hwindowCompatibleDC); ReleaseDC(hwnd, hwindowDC);

    return src;
}
```

Comment: Following lines could be added to avoid memory leak: 
DeleteObject (hbwindow); 
DeleteDC(hwindowCompatibleDC); 
ReleaseDC(hwnd, hwindowDC);

Comment: Great. Thanks for the code. I've added the code of @Steck to your post to make it complete.

Comment: Thanks for the code, it works perfectly. Added information of your initial question to get handle of screen. Added comment of @Steck to my code and edited your answer with those memory frees. Hope that was ok.

Comment: I'm trying to use this to capture a MEmu window. It captures just the "frame" of the windows (window title, menu items, close button, etc). Any idea why this happens?

Comment: Does this work in Win10? With some adjustments in code about height and width, for me it returns black frame when `hwnd` is window handle though when it's NULL it does what it's supposed to, return whole screen.

Answer (score 13):

A better way to do it is do it while allocating memory to the pixels **only once. so the only copy done here is the one that made by BitBlt**

[image]

```
int main()

{

    int x_size = 800, y_size = 600; // <-- Your res for the image





    HBITMAP hBitmap; // <-- The image represented by hBitmap

    Mat matBitmap; // <-- The image represented by mat





    // Initialize DCs

    HDC hdcSys = GetDC(NULL); // Get DC of the target capture..
    HDC hdcMem = CreateCompatibleDC(hdcSys); // Create compatible DC 






    void *ptrBitmapPixels; // <-- Pointer variable that will contain the potinter for the pixels









    // Create hBitmap with Pointer to the pixels of the Bitmap
    BITMAPINFO bi; HDC hdc;
    ZeroMemory(&bi, sizeof(BITMAPINFO));
    bi.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
    bi.bmiHeader.biWidth = x_size;
    bi.bmiHeader.biHeight = -y_size;  //negative so (0,0) is at top left

    bi.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;

    bi.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 32;
    hdc = GetDC(NULL);
    hBitmap = CreateDIBSection(hdc, &bi, DIB_RGB_COLORS, &ptrBitmapPixels, NULL, 0);
    // ^^ The output: hBitmap & ptrBitmapPixels


    // Set hBitmap in the hdcMem 
    SelectObject(hdcMem, hBitmap);



    // Set matBitmap to point to the pixels of the hBitmap
    matBitmap = Mat(y_size, x_size, CV_8UC4, ptrBitmapPixels, 0);
    //                ^^ note: first it is y, then it is x. very confusing

    // * SETUP DONE *




    // Now update the pixels using BitBlt
    BitBlt(hdcMem, 0, 0, x_size, y_size, hdcSys, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);


    // Just to do some image processing on the pixels.. (Dont have to to this)
    Mat matRef = matBitmap(Range(100, 200), Range(100, 200));
    //                              y1    y2            x1     x2
    bitwise_not(matRef, matRef); // Invert the colors in this x1,x2,y1,y2




    // Display the results through Mat
    imshow("Title", matBitmap);

    // Wait until some key is pressed

    waitKey(0);


    return 0;


}
```

**Note that no error handling done here to make it simple to understand but you have to do error handling in your code!**

**Hope this helps**

Comment: Why `GetDC(NULL)` twice?

Comment: Cool. It's worth noting that the code above if used in repeatable scenarios (loop for example) will leave memory leaks and will flood your heap memory / crash application in a long run.

You have to call DeleteObject(hBitmap); and matBitmap.release() after you done with your image.