# OpenCV: assertation failed ((img.depth() == CV_8U || img.depth() == CV_32F) && img.type() == templ.type())

Tags: c++, opencv, depth

I get this error from above and don't know how to avoid it. 
My aim is to get a screenshot and then perform a template matching on it to see if an icon is shown on the screen at this moment. Till now it's just the position of the icon.
My code:

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>


using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

Mat hwnd2mat();

/// Global Variables
Mat img; Mat templ; Mat result;

int main()
{
  /// Load image and template
  templ = imread( "Template.bmp",1);
  templ.convertTo(templ, CV_8U);

  //img = imread( "Image.jpg", 1 );
  img = hwnd2mat();


  /// Create the result matrix
  int result_cols =  img.cols - templ.cols + 1;
  int result_rows = img.rows - templ.rows + 1;

  result.create( result_cols, result_rows, CV_8U);

  /// Do the Matching and Normalize
  matchTemplate( img, templ, result, CV_TM_SQDIFF );
  normalize( result, result, 0, 1, NORM_MINMAX, -1, Mat() );

  /// Localizing the best match with minMaxLoc
  double minVal; double maxVal; Point minLoc; Point maxLoc;
  Point matchLoc;

  minMaxLoc( result, &minVal, &maxVal, &minLoc, &maxLoc, Mat() );

  /// show best position
  matchLoc = minLoc;
  cout<<matchLoc<<" is best position"<<endl;

  waitKey(0);
  return 0;
}

Mat hwnd2mat(){

    HWND hwnd = GetDesktopWindow();
    HDC hwindowDC,hwindowCompatibleDC;

    int height,width,srcheight,srcwidth;
    HBITMAP hbwindow;
    Mat src;
    BITMAPINFOHEADER  bi;

    hwindowDC=GetDC(hwnd);
    hwindowCompatibleDC=CreateCompatibleDC(hwindowDC);
    SetStretchBltMode(hwindowCompatibleDC,COLORONCOLOR);  

    RECT windowsize;    // get the height and width of the screen
    GetClientRect(hwnd, &windowsize);

    srcheight = windowsize.bottom;
    srcwidth = windowsize.right;
    height = windowsize.bottom/1;  //change this to whatever size you want to resize to
    width = windowsize.right/1;

    src.create(height,width,CV_8U);

    // create a bitmap
    hbwindow = CreateCompatibleBitmap( hwindowDC, width, height);
    bi.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
    bi.biWidth = width;    
    bi.biHeight = -height;  //this is the line that makes it draw upside down or not
    bi.biPlanes = 1;    
    bi.biBitCount = 32;    
    bi.biCompression = BI_RGB;    
    bi.biSizeImage = 0;  
    bi.biXPelsPerMeter = 0;    
    bi.biYPelsPerMeter = 0;    
    bi.biClrUsed = 0;    
    bi.biClrImportant = 0;

    // use the previously created device context with the bitmap
    SelectObject(hwindowCompatibleDC, hbwindow);
    // copy from the window device context to the bitmap device context
    StretchBlt( hwindowCompatibleDC, 0,0, width, height, hwindowDC, 0, 0,srcwidth,srcheight, SRCCOPY); //change SRCCOPY to NOTSRCCOPY for wacky colors !
    GetDIBits(hwindowCompatibleDC,hbwindow,0,height,src.data,(BITMAPINFO *)&bi,DIB_RGB_COLORS);  //copy from hwindowCompatibleDC to hbwindow

    DeleteObject(hbwindow);
    DeleteDC(hwindowCompatibleDC);
    ReleaseDC(hwnd, hwindowDC);

    return src;
}
```

The function with the screenshot is not my own work, i got it from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14148758/how-to-capture-the-desktop-in-opencv-ie-turn-a-bitmap-into-a-mat)

Any Ideas what to do?

Thanks for help, best regards!

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that the function `hwnd2mat` is returning a grayscale image of type `CV_8UC1` while `templ` is a color image of type `CV_8UC3`. So the assertion is failing on the function `matchTemplate` due to the failing condition `img.type() == templ.type()`. You may load the image as grayscale to avoid the error.

```
templ = imread( "Template.bmp",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
```

**UPDATE:**

It is worth noting that the function `hwnd2mat` is not working in its current form and it returns an invalid image. The original code creates the output image of type `CV_8UC4` which is the correct approach.

```
src.create(height,width,CV_8UC4);
```

Either you may convert `src` to grayscale before returning from `hwnd2mat`, or you may convert `templ` to 4 channel image. Anyway, the point is that both image must have same type for `matchTemplate` to work.

Comment: Hi!
Thank you for your answer. I also found that, that the types didn't match and fixed all to CV_8U.
You are right when saying, the hwnd2mat doesn't work, it just gives a plain grey image. Unfortunately I have no idea what is wrong there...

Comment: Now the screenshot works, but I still have troubles with the types. /// Load image and template
  templ = imread("Template.bmp", 1);
  templ.convertTo(templ, CV_8UC4);
  
  //img = imread( "Image.jpg", 1 );
  img = hwnd2mat(GetDesktopWindow());
  img.convertTo(img, CV_8UC4);
  cout<<"img "<<img.type()<<"    templ "<<templ.type()<<endl; this gives me differt types for img and templ. why?