# OpenCV + Tesseract for text recognition on video frames in realtime

Tags: opencv, ocr, tesseract

I am trying to use tesseract for frames captured by opencv from windows screen. I am not using a camera feed here instead I am trying to capture certain message that appears in a message box of a certain color. I am able to crop out the part of the screen that shows the message box and I want to use tesseract for reading the message. I am able to read the message using tesseract from the screenshot of the same message box cropped image but when I try to do the same in real time screen capture it is giving really bad output.

The screenshot is saved using imwrite() of opencv on the same Mat image which is passed to tesseract.

Can anyone explain why is this happening?

How can I make it work?

Regards

Comment: I am using windows api to capture screen in full resolution and able to convert it to opencv Mat image using the description given [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14148758/how-to-capture-the-desktop-in-opencv-ie-turn-a-bitmap-into-a-mat)

Comment: I have solved it myself there was a bug in the way I was using the tesseract api.