# How to find the position of an object on the screen?

Tags: c++, c, opencv, webcam, tracking

I am trying to detect the pixel position of an object on the screen. In my case: a soccer ball which changes the position on the screen each 10-20s. 
My first approach was to use a Webcam, record my own screen and then detect the object by using openCV and translate the position to a pixel position. But I think there must be an easier solution. If anybody knows another approach, please tell me your idea. I want to use c/c++ if possible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For starters, this entirely depends on what graphics API you're using (i.e. GDI, Xorg, etc). Second, using openCV is definitely not the best approach. You can usually just grab a direct screenshot of the screen and do your processing from there.

Comment: Maybe this will help you out http://opencv-srf.blogspot.com.br/2010/09/object-detection-using-color-seperation.html

Comment: you can grab the screen with opencv directly. see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14148758/how-to-capture-the-desktop-in-opencv-ie-turn-a-bitmap-into-a-mat). or you can use another screen capture lib like [FFmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/)/[Libav](https://libav.org/).

Comment: Ok, I didn´t know, that I can grap the screen directly. Thanks for that hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VLC can stream your screen over RTP/HTTP/etc and opencv video capture can open it, e.g. `cv::VideoCapture("http://...")` For VLC's settings follow the description here: https://grok.lsu.edu/m/article.aspx?articleId=14625

Comment: That seems to be a good approach, thanks !