# How to convert ATL::CImage to cv::Mat?

Tags: c++, opencv, mfc, atl

I want to convert from `ATL::CImage` to `cv::Mat` for image handling in opencv(C++).
Could you please help to convert this object?

I got `CImage` from windows screen shot(Using MFC).
Then, I want to handle image in OpenCV Mat object.

I did not know how to convert.

- C++ Project(VC 2017)
- MFC
- OpenCV 3.4.6

---

```
CImage image;
int cx;
int cy;
CWnd* pWndDesktop = CWnd::GetDesktopWindow();
CWindowDC srcDC(pWndDesktop);

Rect rcDesktopWindow;
::GetWindowRect(pWndDesktop->m_hWnd, %rcDesktopWindow);

cx = (rcDesktopWindow.right - rcDesktopWindow.left);
cy = (rcDesktopWindow.bottom - rcDesktopWindow.top);

image.create(cx, cy, srcDC.GetDeviceCaps(BITPIXEL));

CDC* pDC = CDC::FromHandle(image.GetDC());
pDC->BitBlt(0, 0, cx, cy, &srcDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

image.ReleaseDC();

cv::Mat mat;

// I want set image to mat!
mat = image???
```

Can not convert `ATL::Image` to `cv::Mat`.

Comment: You could just eliminate the middleman and have one function to get the screenshot as a Mat. This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34466993/opencv-desktop-capture or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14148758/how-to-capture-the-desktop-in-opencv-ie-turn-a-bitmap-into-a-mat

Comment: The simplest (but rather daft) approach would be to save it to file (there seems to be a member function to do that) and then load it back with `imread`. It also seems that you can save into an in-memory stream, so you could then feed the resulting buffer to `imdecode` and avoid using the filesystem. The best approach would be to get a pixel buffer with known layout that's understood by `Mat` (row-major, top to bottom ideally so you don't need to flip it).. then you just need to create a `Mat` header to match the data. Only ever had to go from `Mat` to GDI object, so will need to research.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CImage` creates a bottom-top bitmap if height is positive. You have to pass a negative height to create top-bottom bitmap for `mat`

Use `CImage::GetBits` to retrieve the bits as follows:

```
HDC hdc = GetDC(0);
RECT rc;
GetClientRect(GetDesktopWindow(), &rc);
int cx = rc.right;
int cy = rc.bottom;

CImage image;
image.Create(cx, -cy, 32);

BitBlt(image.GetDC(), 0, 0, cx, cy, hdc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
image.ReleaseDC();
ReleaseDC(0, hdc);

cv::Mat mat;
mat.create(cy, cx, CV_8UC4);
memcpy(mat.data, image.GetBits(), cy * cx * 4);

//or borrow pixel data from CImage 
cv::Mat mat(cy, cx, CV_8UC4, image.GetBits());
```

Or force a deep copy as follows:

```
cv::Mat mat;
mat = cv::Mat(cy, cx, CV_8UC4, image.GetBits()).clone();
```

Note, `CImage` makes its own allocation for pixel data. And `Mat` needs to make its own allocation, or it has to borrow from `CImage` which can be tricky.

If you are just taking a screen shot, you can do that with plain Windows API, then write directly to `cv::Mat`. This way there is a single allocation (a bit faster) and `mat` does not rely on other objects. Example:

```
void foo()
{
    HDC hdc = ::GetDC(0);

    RECT rc;
    ::GetClientRect(::GetDesktopWindow(), &rc);
    int cx = rc.right;
    int cy = rc.bottom;
    cv::Mat mat;
    mat.create(cy, cx, CV_8UC4);

    HBITMAP hbitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, cx, cy);
    HDC memdc = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
    HBITMAP oldbmp = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(memdc, hbitmap);
    BitBlt(memdc, 0, 0, cx, cy, hdc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

    BITMAPINFOHEADER bi = { sizeof(bi), cx, -cy, 1, 32, BI_RGB };
    GetDIBits(hdc, hbitmap, 0, cy, mat.data, (BITMAPINFO*)&bi, DIB_RGB_COLORS);

    //GDI cleanup:
    SelectObject(memdc, oldbmp);
    DeleteDC(memdc);
    DeleteObject(hbitmap);
    ::ReleaseDC(0, hdc);
}
```

---

Edit: 
Changed `mat.data = (unsigned char*)image.GetBits();` to 
`memcpy(mat.data, image.GetBits(), cy * cx * 4);`

Changed `ReleaseDC(0, hdc)` to `::ReleaseDC(0, hdc)` to avoid conflict with `CWnd::ReleaseDC(dc)`

Comment: By resetting the `data` member, you're potentially leaking the buffer (or at the least asking for trouble -- don't really want to dig through the implementation to find any possible pitfalls due to messing with its exposed internal state). Just use the [appropriate constructor](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.3/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a51615ebf17a64c968df0bf49b4de6a3a) to create a header wrapping that buffer correctly. Fix that, and i'll revise my vote.

Comment: Might be also useful to mention that the `Mat` is only good as long as `image` is in scope.

Comment: @DanMašek You don't have to dig through the source code. You can read the docs for `data` which is "exposed", and you can check for leaks. Leaks don't occur in this case because `Mat` keeps track of its own allocation. Your suggestion is certainly more efficient and safer, but the question is for `Mat mat;` that's up to the asker to rewrite it...

Comment: Yeah, I see that `UMatData` member object will handle the originally allocated memory. But you're definitely breaking the internal state right now, since `datastart`, `dataend` and `datalimit` still point to the internally allocated memory, while `data` points to completely different block. So things like `locateROI` and maybe `adjustROI` probably won't be very happy at best. Not to mention you're allocating a useless chunk of memory. I really don't see a reason to do this, especially having pointed out a cleaner approach. I'm sorry, but I'd never pass code like this through a review.

Comment: "up to the asker to rewrite it" -- based on my observations on SO, I expect a lot of beginners will take this code as the right thing to do, without giving it a second thought. Hence, to me, it seems a bit irresponsible to write code like this in an answer.

Comment: @DanMašek, Yes, the extra allocation is not efficient (in fairness it's better than saving the image to disk and reading it again) I updated the answer to avoid the extra allocation and fix possible problems with the pointer.

Comment: "better than saving" -- absolutely, that was just the minimum effort approach that came to mind with minimum research. Your approach (other than the bit I complained about) would be what I'd look for (and the pure WinAPI solution is even better). Thanks for the update.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/types_c.h>
#include <atlimage.h>

using namespace cv;

Mat CImage2Mat(CImage cimg)
{
    BITMAP bmp;
    ::GetObject(cimg.Detach(), sizeof(BITMAP), &bmp);

    int nChannels = bmp.bmBitsPixel == 1 ? 1 : bmp.bmBitsPixel / 8;
    int depth = bmp.bmBitsPixel == 1 ? IPL_DEPTH_1U : IPL_DEPTH_8U;

    IplImage* img = cvCreateImageHeader(cvSize(bmp.bmWidth, bmp.bmHeight), depth, nChannels);

    img->imageData = (char*)malloc(bmp.bmHeight * bmp.bmWidth * nChannels * sizeof(char));
    memcpy(img->imageData, (char*)(bmp.bmBits), bmp.bmHeight * bmp.bmWidth * nChannels);
    cvFlip(img, img, 0);
    return cvarrToMat(static_cast<IplImage*>(img));
}
```

Usage:

```
CImage cimg;
cimg.Load(L"resim.png");

Mat img = CImage2Mat(cimg);
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually, this scenario occurs when working with image processing in MFC windows application development. I was developing an MFC based app that captures the images from Canon DSLR using the EDSDK (canon SDK). I used this solution (time saving), the problem I faced was degradation of the image resolution!

Solution here! 100% working.
https://github.com/wlrl/convertType