# OpenCV Fisher face error

Tags: c++, opencv

i tried to run the fisher algorithm provided by  openCV community.
http://docs.opencv.org/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/facerec_tutorial.html#tp91

But it produces the following error.

```
OpenCV Error: Image step is wrong (The matrix is not continuous, thus its number 
of rows can not be changed) in unknown function, file 
......\src\opencv\modules\core\src\matrix.cpp, line 802"
```

And found out that error is caused by,

```
          Ptr<FaceRecognizer> model = createFisherFaceRecognizer();
          model->train(images, labels);  //Error occurs when i cal this method
```

Images i am feeding are the same size. following links say it could be due to release libraries.

[OpenCV 2.0 C++ API using imshow: returns unhandled exception and "bad-flag"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2623163/opencv-2-0-c-api-using-imshow-returns-unhandled-exception-and-bad-flag)

[Getting OpenCV Error "Image step is wrong" in Fisherfaces.train() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10961586/getting-opencv-error-image-step-is-wrong-in-fisherfaces-train-method)

But i removed all the release libraries from the project and using the debug mode in visual studio 2010. I am using OpenCV 2.4.5

But i could not go pass the error.

please help.

Thank you.

Comment: are you using bmp files ? your images might be *padded* / non continuous somehow(you can't reshape padded images, that's what the error says), and the FisherFaceRecognizer does not like that. converting them to a different format (pgm) might help then. also check your csv file containing the image names there, any chance you've got some *non-image* in there ? ( e.g., the att database has a readme.txt )