# window "Image" has a strange caption: "@ -|TM", which is not dependent on the name

Tags: opencv, window, label, loadimage

I am aware my question is similar to:

[OpenCV 2.0 C++ API using imshow: returns unhandled exception and "bad-flag"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2623163/opencv-2-0-c-api-using-imshow-returns-unhandled-exception-and-bad-flag)

Though I hv tried all the suggested and verified solutions from this page as well as other related pages, I still face the same problem of corrupted window names. Here is my code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "cv.h"
#include "highgui.h"
#include "cxcore.h"
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>   
#include <malloc.h>   
#include <math.h>   
#include"ip.h"  
#include"histogram.h"
#include <opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp>
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

void main()
{
    IplImage *img01 = cvLoadImage("E:\liberty.jpg",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
    cv::Mat img1(img01, false);
    cv::namedWindow("Image 1");
    cv::imshow("Image 1",img1);
    cv::waitKey(0);
    cv::destroyWindow("Image 1");
}
```

What should i do?Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Is your image loading to img01?

Try changing '\' to'/' in **IplImage *img01 = cvLoadImage("E:\liberty.jpg",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);**

Comment: Pranjal, the image loads. Tried ur method. Still the same problem.

Comment: All I did was change the '\' and it worked for me. So maybe you need to check your libraries - you've used both _# include " "_ & _# include < >_ for linking to the OpenCV libs - just wondering

Comment: Ur guess is as good as mine @Pranjal. #include"..." is for user defined headers and <..> is pre defined headers. So that doesnt make too much difference. as for the libraries, i have added all of them, and double checked with the dlls too. Unfortunately still the same. Did u implement this very program?

Comment: I'm guessing you've tried all of this, but if it's any use, try - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cgo0UitHfp8